# Vite command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, vite

I'm trying to just run a basic vite build and every time I run "npm run dev" I get this error:

```
rijul@Rijuls-MacBook-Pro spotify-profile-demo % npm run dev

> spotify-profile-demo@0.0.0 dev
> vite

sh: vite: command not found
```

I'm not really sure what to do. I've already tried npm install again, and deleting the npm_modules folder along with the package-lock.json file and trying npm install again. Not sure where to go from here. I also reinstalled node js. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It's not possble to help without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Provide your package.json as a start.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the package.json file in your project. Normally, there is "vite" field in "devDependencies" object. And then you can run npm install to have a try. If "npm install" command does not work, you can try to use "Yarn" instead.